# How to remove one of the two identical string value in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I am developing an android App that reads RFID Tag number and shows it in a textView. But if the same tag number is read again I just want to show it once in second textView.

[image]

What can I do to show the tag number once in the second TextView considering that the first Textview contains the tag number more than once?
Here is the code that i wrote to display in second textView:

```
rfidTagNo = textView.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s","");
    TextView rfid; 
    rfid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rfidTag);
    rfid.setText(rfidTagNo);
```

Additionally I want to display only Tag number in the second textView other than any messages shown in the first TextView e.g "approximate your card to the reader".

Comment: make an arrayList and save each one you got 
if list is contains RFID then don't show it
then print what do you have in arrayList

Comment: if I make an arrayList then I need to split the first TextView string based on newline character. right? And insert the values in that arrayList. Is there regex to do the same thing?

Comment: Man, when you take a tag add it to the arrayList

Comment: Use hashset instread

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a novice developer. Its great to learn a new thing called Hashset. @BasilBattikhi

Comment: You are welcome man :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you write in the first `TextView` save your tags in an `ArrayList<String>`.

```
ArrayList<String> myTags = new ArrayList<>();
// fetch tags
myTags.add(currentTag);
// set text to first `TextView` & check if it is already added
if (!myTags.contains(currentTag)) {
   rfid.setText(currentTag);
}
```